# ¿Cómo puedo pasar este trigger a oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlite, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_log AFTER INSERT 
ON src_reservarhora
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO src_registro(EMP_ID, ENTRY_DATE, FECHA, HORA ) VALUES (new.ID, datetime('now'), new.fecha, new.hora);
END
```

lo intente crear de la siguiente manera

```
create TRIGGER  audit_log AFTER INSERT 
ON src_reservarhora
for each row
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO src_registro
   VALUES (new.id_reserva, datetime(short, short), new.fecha, new.hora);
END
;
```

me dice ORA-00984: columna no permitida aquí

esta es la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE src_registro(
   EMP_ID number NOT NULL,
   ENTRY_DATE varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
   FECHA  NOT NULL,
   HORA varchar2(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Probaste algo? Te falló? Cómo te falló? Qué problema tienes?

Comment: es un trigger que desarrolle en sqllite  pero no lo eh podido crear en oracle

Comment: Gracias por completar tu pregunta. Qué dato intentas generar con esa función datetime(que no existe en Oracle)? De qué tipo son las columnas de la tabla `src_registro`?

Comment: con el datetime quiero sacar la fecha y hora de la ejecución del insert

Answer (score 0):

La solución es que uses SYSDATE ayudandote con [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) para darle formato y que entre en tu columna `varchar2`; SYSDATE es la palabra clave para halar el datetime actual en Oracle.

```
create TRIGGER  audit_log AFTER INSERT 
ON src_reservarhora
for each row
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO src_registro
   VALUES (new.id_reserva, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF'), new.fecha, new.hora);
END
;
```

Ahora bien, como sugerencia, yo no guardaría los timestamp como varchar y usaría un tipo de dato que me permita más adelante operar con fechas y horas de forma nativa. Puede ser DATE o TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE TABLE src_registro(
   EMP_ID number NOT NULL,
   ENTRY_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
   FECHA  NOT NULL,
   HORA varchar2(10) NOT NULL
);
/

create TRIGGER  audit_log AFTER INSERT 
ON src_reservarhora
for each row
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO src_registro
   VALUES (new.id_reserva, SYSDATE, new.fecha, new.hora);
END
;
```

Comment: Lo probé y sigue devolviendo ORA-00984: columna no permitida aquí

Comment: específicamente el error lo resalta en new.hora

Comment: @FelipePrieto revisemos los campos de src_reservarhora entonces